# Undefined (reading 'coords') using @ionic-native/geolocation - ionic / react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework

I am trying to center the map in the geoposition and I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coords')

If I console log the position in the getLocationHandler, the object seems to have the coordinates.

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation";
import { IonLoading } from "@ionic/react";

const Map = (props) => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState();

  const getLocationHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      setPosition(position);
    } catch (e) {}
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocationHandler();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <IonLoading
        isOpen={isLoading}
        message={"Getting Location..."}
        onDidDismiss={() => setIsLoading(false)}
      ></IonLoading>
      <div className="map">
        <div className="google-map" style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
          <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: .... }}
            defaultCenter={
              {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
              }
            }
            defaultZoom={11}>
          </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first render, `position` will be undefined so when you're trying to use `position.coords.latitude` it's throwing that error.  I would probably leverage your `isLoading` state and only render the second part of your component when that is false -

```
<div className="google-map" style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
  {!isLoading && (
    <GoogleMapReact
      ...etc
  )}
</div>
```

Also, it would probably make sense to set the initial value of `isLoading` to true instead of manually setting that to true inside your async loading function.

Alternatively, instead of checking `isLoading` you could directly check `position?.coords?.latitude`